# Pointer Arithmetic with Arrays

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pointer-arithmetic

I am new to C programming and I am getting confused with the pointer math.  I have an array of characters of size 32.  It is my understanding that this means that the array is also 32 bytes since a character variable is 1 byte big therefore `32 characters * 1 byte = 32 bytes`.  The problem is when having a function that has a void pointer that is pointing to an array of characters as described before.  I believe that the code segment

```
for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
*((int*) raw_sk + count) = 0
```

should set all of the slots in the raw_sk buffer should be set to 0.  However, when I run the program, I get a segmentation fault.  I thought that it could be possibly be the fact that I am adding count to the address.  I thought that if I were to add one to an address I would be moving to the next slot in the array.  Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?  The function I am using is below.
Thanks!

```
void
write_skfile (const char *skfname, void *raw_sk, size_t raw_sklen)
{
  int fdsk = 0;
  char *s = NULL;
  int status = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int size = (raw_sklen);


  /* armor the raw symmetric key in raw_sk using armor64 */
  s = armor64(raw_sk, raw_sklen);

  /* now let's write the armored symmetric key to skfname */

  if ((fdsk = open (skfname, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, 0600)) == -1) {
    perror (getprogname ());

    /*scrubs the armored buffer*/
    for(count = 0; count < armor64len(s); count++)
    s[count] = '0';

    free (s);

    /* scrub the buffer that's holding the key before exiting */
   for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    *((int*)raw_sk + count) = 0;

    exit (-1);
  }
  else {
    status = write (fdsk, s, strlen (s));
    if (status != -1) {
      status = write (fdsk, "\n", 1);
    }

   for (count = 0; (size_t)count < 22; count++)
    *((int*)raw_sk + count) = 0;

   free (s);
    close (fdsk);

    /* do not scrub the key buffer under normal circumstances
       (it's up to the caller) */ 

    if (status == -1) {
      printf ("%s: trouble writing symmetric key to file %s\n", 
          getprogname (), skfname);
      perror (getprogname ());

    /* scrub the buffer that's holding the key before exiting */

       /* scrub the buffer that's holding the key before exiting MY CODE
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    *((int*)raw_sk + count) = 0;*/

      exit (-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing the pointer by the size of an `int`.  That is wrong.  If you want to zero out the array you increment by the size of a `char`.  Better yet, just use `memset`.

Comment: so how could I increment by the size of a char? I thought that the compiler would do that for me, clearly I was mistaken.  I will look into how to use memset.

Comment: @tpar44: You're casting `raw_sk` to an `int*`.  Pointer arithmetic knows how to increment given the type of a pointer.  for example, adding 1 to a char pointer increments the pointer by 1 byte.  Adding 1 to an int pointer increments by 4 bytes(most of the time).  We can generalize that and say that adding *n* to a pointer of type *x* increments the pointer by `n * sizeof(x)`.  So, if you had cast `raw)_sk` to a `char*` it would have been fine.  Of course, the idiomatic way to do it would be to create a temporary pointer and simply increment that instead of adding a `count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterates over `size*sizeof(int)` bytes in total (where most probably `sizeof(int)==4`), but the array is only `size` bytes large. Hence, segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do

```
*((char*) raw_sk + count) = 0
```

since I assume raw_sk is pointing to char array

pointer arithmatic works by moving the memory address by size of type so in this case you want char